# Squid Server Logs doesn't show actual Web URL

Tags: logging, freebsd, squid

I have configured microtik router as a hotspot and use transparent proxy, and route 80 and 443 traffic towards squid server and attached squid server machine with ip 172.172.172.2 and client machine ip with 10.10.1.253/16. Everything is working fine but when client access any website let say google.com, Squid server access logs shows IP address of website instead of Website URL. And when I opened google's ip address in browser than squid logs shows actual URL https://google.com. Squid version 3.5 installed on freebsd OS.
I used following setting `log_fqdn off` in squid.conf file but it doesn't work.

Output log:

```
1514981582.353 3207 10.10.1.252 TCP_TUNNEL/200 1644069 CONNECT 110.93.194.141:443 - ORIGINAL_DST/110.93.194.141 -  
1514981609.221 30074 10.10.1.252 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3820 CONNECT 110.93.194.141:443 - ORIGINAL_DST/110.93.194.141 - 
1514981646.133 60558 10.10.1.252 TCP_TUNNEL/200 8981 CONNECT 93.184.221.200:443 - ORIGINAL_DST/93.184.221.200 -
```

Comment: @Networker please throw some light on it.

Answer (score 0):

When operating as a transparent proxy, Squid doesn't have access to the domain name being requested. As a transparent proxy, Squid is operating only on the IP/port information when establishing the TCP connection to the downstream server. When the downstream server is served via clear-text HTTP, then Squid may be able to discover the hostname from the HTTP `Host:` header.

However, when acting as a TCP tunnel for TLS-encrypted endpoint it may not be looking for the `server_name` -- this detail is optional and will be encrypted in later TLS revisions.

One more note: per [this thread](http://www.squid-cache.org/mail-archive/squid-users/201407/0164.html) (and [the documentation](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/log_fqdn/)) the `log_fqdn` directive was deprecated after Squid 3.2, and removed in Squid 4.